# How to make a road with border?

Tags: modeling, workflow

I want to make a road with a border as shown in the image below:

[image]

---

Currently I do the next steps:

1. 2 main loop cuts vertically, 6 horizontal loop cuts for curving
2. Select horizontal edges and manually move each of them to the left
3. Additionally, accurate road width by moving vertices
4. Select
   faces and extrude them down

[image]

Is there another methods to do this, maybe more accurate/easier? Also, For example, I badly imagine what will I do if need to extend the existing area.

Comment: there must be a way to do it with Geometry Nodes as well...

Comment: @Luciano, yeah, but, Geometry Nodes...You know...It means I need to learn how things work. Not a solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. add a box as ground and size it

e.g. Add cube -> Tab -> S Z 0.2 Return -> S Shift-Z 20 Return -> Tab

[image]

2. add a bezier curve -> model your street as you want to have it

[image]

3. add 0.6 as extrude value here

[image]

4. add solidify modifier and choose thickness value as wide as your street should be

[image]

[image]

5. hide your street like this:

[image]

6. select your box from 1) and tab on geometry nodes

[image]

6. press New

[image]

7. add these nodes:

[image]

[image]

8. now you can move your ground along the z-axis like this in edit mode:

[image]

9. the big advantage of this node setup is: you can still change your bezierpath/street:

[image]

if you want to have a more flat border, you could add a cube, and use these modifiers:

[image]

then you would get this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Cool, seems to be the best solution. I will wait a bit for another answers, and probably accept Yours

Comment: Keeping the steps non-destructive  is very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

One way it could be done is by modeling a bezier curve to fit your desired road pattern, then creating a square bevel profile in the curve parameters.

You could then convert your curve to mesh, and boolean it from an object such as a cube.

A duplicate bevelled curve could be resized in the Z axis to make the road.

You could also put a  shrink-wrap modifier on the road, projecting the road to the surface if there was displacement.

An advantage of this way of doing it would be that geometry nodes have some of these functions.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer, can You, please describe the steps more?

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was a good method but I hadn't quite thought about how you would make it a routine work flow.  Other responses  will describe that better.

Answer (score 0):

Been experimenting a while, and currently I can admit, that the most comfortable (for me) method is to use Knife tool on plane.

It is way more faster and more easier than using any modifiers, curves and all this stuff. Also, using modifiers requiers cube instead of plane, which gives extra geometry.

The main advantage of cutting is easy-made complicated patterns: curves, unfortunately can't have "branches", so You need to use booleans, or just duplicate stuff. Using knife, it is very simple to cut any pattern you need.

The only advantage I see in modifiers, is, that they are non-destructive, although, fixing stuf with plain "cutted" plane is harder but possible.

1. Go to `Edit mode` (`tab`), and make a cut using knife tool:
   [image]
2. Select face, and choose `Extrude region`

[image]

3. Extrude down

[image]

4. That's it. Now, the bordures can be placed

[image]